# Make recursive function iterative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, python-idle, tail-recursion

When I run the below module, it runs for about 960 recursions:

```
import matplotlib
import pylab

xStart = 1
debug = 'off'
xList = []
calcList = []

def collatzCalc(xStart,calcs):
    calc = 0
    xCalc = 0
    xCalc = xStart
    while xCalc > 0:
        if debug == 'on':
            print(round(xCalc))
            print(xList)
            print(calcList)

        if xCalc == 1:
            xList.append(xStart)
            calcList.append(calc)
            xStart += 1
            if debug == 'on':
                print(calcs)
                print('---------------------------')

            calcs += 1
            collatzCalc(xStart,calcs)
        else:
            if xCalc % 2 == 0:
                xCalc = xCalc / 2
                calc += 1
            else:
                xCalc = xCalc * 3 + 1
                calc += 1

calcs = 0
collatzCalc(xStart,calcs)
```

It throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erin Lynch\Desktop\collatzConjecture.py", line 49, in <module>
    collatzCalc(xStart,calcs)
File "C:\Users\Erin Lynch\Desktop\collatzConjecture.py", line 32, in collatzCalc
    collatzCalc(xStart,calcs)
  File "C:\Users\Erin Lynch\Desktop\collatzConjecture.py", line 14, in collatzCalc
    while xCalc > 0:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I know why this is happening, because I read today about recursion limits, but what I'm wanting to know is how I can turn my recursion formulas into iterative ones. I am completely lost on how to do this, and I need help from someone who knows how.

Comment: Are you sure it is the correct code? I cant find "calcs" anywhere except: 
    calcs += 1 (offcourse ignoring the debug print statement)

Comment: Oh sorry. Accidentally took out a little part. Fixing it now!

Comment: If `xCalc == 1` then the function is stuck in an infinite loop because nothing in that clause will alter the value of `xCalc`, so it will forever stay at `xCalc == 1`.

Comment: What happens is `collatzCalc(xStart,calcs)` makes it go back to the `collatzCalc()` function, and below that is `xCalc = 0`.

Comment: `xCalc` is a *local* variable.  What you do to it in the children does not affect parent function.  The parent function will still loop forever.

Comment: That is exactly what I want the parent function to do. So `xCalc` is not the problem according to syntax. Stringing `xCalc` through `xCalc > 0` and `collatzCalc(xStart,calcs)` so many times is what is causing the problem. After about 960 times of doing this, I surpass the recursion limit, which is why I am getting this error.

Comment: The problem is that this affects not only the parent function but *all* instances of this function (because recursive functions are self-similar).  If your intent is to check the Collatz conjecture for all numbers, you only need *one* infinite loop to do this.

Comment: So how can I fix this then?

Comment: The infinite loop should only occur in the outermost function, which means you need to split it into two separate functions: one for looping through all natural numbers, and one for calculating the Collatz sequence.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your responses. If you could post this in an answer, I will upvote and submit as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in this part, the first line is unnecessary since `xCalc` will be immediately overwritten with `xStart`:

```
    xCalc = 0
    xCalc = xStart
```

Secondly, if you observe the code carefully, you see that if `xCalc` ever reaches `1` it will just loop forever:

```
def collatzCalc(xStart,calcs):
    ...
    xCalc = xStart
    while xCalc > 0:
        ...
        if xCalc == 1:
            ...
            collatzCalc(xStart,calcs)
        else:
            ...
```

Since `xCalc` is a *local variable*, other instances of `collatzCalc` cannot modify this variable.  The function will just keep looping forever.  While it makes sense to loop forever in the "outermost" function since you're checking the Collatz conjecture, it does not make sense to do it *recursively*.

I think it's because you have confused two distinct parts of this program:

1. You want to check the Collatz conjecture for every natural number.
2. You want to calculate the Collatz sequence.

Let's address the first one because it's easier.  To check the Collatz conjecture, you just need a simple loop:

```
def checkCollatz(xStart=1, debug=False):
    xList = []
    calcList = []
    while True:
        calc = collatzCalc(xStart, debug=debug)
        xList.append(xStart)
        calcList.append(calc)
        if debug:
            print(xStart - 1)
            print('---------------------------')
        xStart += 1
```

Here, I have turned the global variables (`xList`, `calcList`, `xStart`, and `debug`) into local variables of this outermost function.  (You might also want to pick more descriptive names for them too.)  Note that I have completely eliminated the `calcs` variable because it appears to be identical to `xStart`, except always lower by one.

Now, to calculate the Collatz sequence, I can reuse what you already have (stripping out the parts that were used in `checkCollatz`):

```
def collatzCalc(xCalc, debug=False):
    calc = 0
    while xCalc > 0:
        if debug:
            print(xCalc)
        if xCalc == 1:
            return calc
        else:
            if xCalc % 2 == 0:
                xCalc = xCalc // 2
            else:
                xCalc = xCalc * 3 + 1
            calc += 1
```

The use of `round` is unnecessary since Collatz sequences are always integers.  Additionally, one should use integer division (`//`) instead of floating-point division (`/`) because `/` will coerce your numbers into floating-point numbers.

Notice that there is no recursion at all in this code.  The recursion has been eliminated and transformed into the loop in `checkCollatz` (notice that there are now *two* `while` loops instead of one).  Your original code was already mostly iterative so converting it into a recursive one was not very involved.

As a side note, notice that by splitting the function into two separate functions, there are now much fewer variables and the code is a lot easier to read.